# edit text in list view empty or not

Tags: android, iteration

In my list view ,I have `Edittext` and some `textviews`. when I am trying to iterate over `listview` to get `edittext` values, I got some problems.I want to perform actions only if my `edittext` in the `listview` is not empty. otherwise i want to continue the iteration.I need only non empty values from the `edittexts` when iterate through `listview`. my `listview` name is "list" here.
my code is

```
if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ed2 = (EditText) list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.pcs);
                if (ed2.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                    TextView im_codetext = (TextView) vie.findViewById(R.id.code);
                    imcode = im_codetext.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
                        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        Cursor cr = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_srp_pc, im_subgroup_code  from itemmaster where im_code =" + imcode, null);

                        while (cr.moveToNext()) {
                            srppc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("im_srp_pc"));
                            String subcode = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("im_subgroup_code"));
                            databas.put("subgp", subcode);
                        }
                        srps = Float.valueOf(srpval);
                        qtys = Integer.valueOf(ed2.getText().toString());

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        srps = 0;
                    }
                    float amnts = srps * qtys;
                    sumnet = sumnet + amnts;
                    else{
                        Log.v(" empty", " empty");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

My adapter class is

```
 public  class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(datas != null && datas.size() != 0){
                return datas.size();    
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return datas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //ViewHolder holder = null;
            final  ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = Orders.this.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_simple_row, null);
                holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.srp);
                holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                                    holder.editText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pcs); 

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.ref = position;
            String [] names = new String[550];
            String [] codes = new String[550];
            String [] prize = new String[550];

                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Orders.this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp "
                    + " from itemmaster", null);

                c.moveToFirst();

                while (c.moveToNext()){

                    Log.v("item detailss", c.toString());   
               String cod = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code"));
             codes[c.getPosition()] =cod;
                String desc1  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"));
                names[c.getPosition()] = desc1;

                 String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"));
                prize[c.getPosition()] = price;
                                }

                 holder.textView1.setText(names[position+1]);
                holder.textview3.setText(codes[position+1]);
                     holder.textView2.setText(prize[position+1]);



            holder.editText2.setText(arrTemp[position]);

            holder.editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     // arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();

                }
            });

            return convertView;


    }
        private class ViewHolder {

             public Object list;
            TextView textView1,textView2,textview3;
         EditText editText1,editText2;
             int ref;
            }
    }
```

please help.thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your adapter class...

Comment: @Ancee I just posted my adapter class .please take a look

Comment: what you want ? check all edittext are empty or not?

Comment: when running the application, i need to enter values in the edit text. not in all rows, i pick rows randomly. My problem is that when iterating through list, the addition performs for edit texts which have no value. i just want to do actions only on non empty edit texts. I am not sure about how to pick non empty edit texts on the list view.

Comment: this I really wants ,if the edit text is not empty then perform the corresponding action. otherwise continue the code until the list view ends.if it is empty then check for the next row whether its edit text is empty or not.

Comment: @Brijesh Goswami please read my question.view recycling is not my problem. I have a huge list view.and each time I am running the application i do not want to make entry in all edit text. so when i click a button i just want to get the values from edit text by avoiding the empty edit texts

Comment: Check it by the length of your edittext

Answer (score 0):

I have a Solution.

Declare a HashMap in your custom adapter class.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public HashMap<Integer,String> textMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    ....
```

In getView() Method get text from HasMap and set in EditText.

```
 @Override

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    holder.editText = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    holder.editText.setText(textMap.get(position));
    ....
```

And in TextChangeListner add text in HashMap by position.

```
holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                textMap.put(position,holder.editText.getText().toString());

            }
        });
```

Now in your Activity you can get HashMap of adapter and get its value by position. and if there is no text in particuller position ,means edttext is empty.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,names);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, customAdapter.textMap.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
```